# Problems with Setting "If" Statements in VB using Checkboxes

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to total the values assigned to check boxes when they are checked and display in a text box. This was a bonus problem and wasn't covered in class so as a beginner, I may be lost in multiple areas. Thank you in advance.

```
Public Class frmBooking
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
        Dim baseCruiseCosts, prepaidGratuities, salesTax, grandTotal As Single
        Dim travelOptions As Double
        baseCruiseCosts = txtCosts.Text
        travelOptions = txtTravelOps.Text
        prepaidGratuities = txtGratuities.Text
        salesTax = txtTax.Text
        grandTotal = baseCruiseCosts + travelOptions + prepaidGratuities + salesTax
        txtGrandTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(grandTotal)
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmBooking_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblDate.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkInsurance_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkInsurance.CheckedChanged
        Dim sum, travelOptions As Double
        If chkInsurance.Checked Then
            sum += 90
        End If
        If chkInsurance.Checked = False Then
            txtTravelOps.Text = travelOptions
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkTickets_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkTickets.CheckedChanged
        Dim sum, travelOptions As Double
        If chkTickets.Checked Then
            sum += 30
        End If
        If chkTickets.Checked = False Then
            txtTravelOps.Text = travelOptions
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkBottomless_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBottomless.CheckedChanged
        Dim sum, travelOptions As Double
        If chkBottomless.Checked Then
            sum += 85
        End If
        If chkBottomless.Checked = False Then
            txtTravelOps.Text = travelOptions
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkPreReg_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkPreReg.CheckedChanged
        Dim sum, travelOptions As Double
        If chkPreReg.Checked Then
            sum += 19.95
        End If
        If chkPreReg.Checked = False Then
            txtTravelOps.Text = travelOptions
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: When doing calculations involving money, always use `Decimal` instead of `Double` or `Single`.

Comment: Sorry I voted down this question. It really isn't possible to tell from your question OR from the code... what you are trying to do here. If you have a compute button, you really don't need the checkbox checkers, though I am not sure what the second stanza is supposed to do since they  reference variables that are out of scope..

Answer (score 0):

you created the sum variables inside checkChanged therefore it is only available inside the checkChanged. You must create a global variable or main variable above the form load ( i don't know the term of it so I just call it global/main.)

You can do something like these:

Create 4 variable:
1. grandTotal,sumofTicket,sumofInsurance,sumofBottomless,sumofPreReg.

And when they checked the checkboxes the value must transfer to the designated variable and when they hit the btncompute, add all the variables to the grandTotal variable. Also the variable inside the condition of your checkboxes where = false does not have any value in it.